# Error Generating a WSDL File in 2017 R2 17.200.0401

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to generate a WSDL file for screen CA30400 and when I click on Tools -> Web Service I get the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Line 7:     public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
Line 8:     {
Line 9:         WsdlBuilder.ProcessHelpRequest(context);
Line 10:    }
Line 11: }

Source File: g:\projects\XXXX\Automatica\Projects\XXXX\Website\Frames\WsdlHelp.aspx.cs    Line: 9

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
PX.Data.Process.PXScreenProcessor.HackEtwTrace(Boolean s) +251
PX.Data.Process.PXScreenProcessor.Process(String uri, IPrincipal user, AsyncCallback cb, Action`1 initContext) +2039
PX.Api.ScreenUtils.GetScreenInfoWithoutHttpContext(String screenID) +918
PX.Api.Soap.Screen.WsdlBuilder.GetWsdl(String screenID) +111
PX.Api.Soap.Screen.WsdlBuilder.ProcessHelpRequest(HttpContext context) +989
Frames_WsdlHelp.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in g:\projects\MindOver-Software\Automatica\Projects\RollingDough\Website\Frames\WsdlHelp.aspx.cs:9
ASP.frames_wsdlhelp_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\XXXX\9639ed8b\31eb9aa7\App_Web_5fegsf0t.6.cs:0

System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream) +646

[InvalidOperationException: The XML Web service help page encountered an internal error.]
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteException(Exception e) +229988
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest() +958
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +161
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +866
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +91
```

This is a new installation

Comment: Which .net framework version is set up on the machine and which is configured in the IIS Application Pool your Acumatica is using?

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3046.0

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm getting the same error on a new install when calling a contract-based API endpoint, and it won't go away, even if I reinstall the site from scratch multiple times.